# iOS 6 Add Group to Contacts App

Tags: ios, objective-c, addressbook

I want to provide a group in the native Contacts app but all of the group queries do not work.  I can successfully add contacts to the address book but I want to create my own separate group for my app.  Similar to how Facebook adds their own group.

EDIT: it looks like the groups are added to the default account...is there a way to provide a separate provider?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
//Create new group like so:    
ABAddressBookRef ab = ABAddressBookCreate();
CFErrorRef error;
ABRecordRef group = ABGroupCreate();
ABRecordSetValue(group, kABGroupNameProperty,@"new group", &error);
ABAddressBookAddRecord(ab, group, &error);
ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);

//Create new person and save to this group
ABRecordRef record = ABPersonCreate();
BOOL isSuccess ;

isSuccess  = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonNicknameProperty,@"GroupMember nick name", &error);
isSuccess = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonMiddleNameProperty, @"Middle name", &error);

ABMutableMultiValueRef copyOfPhones = ABMultiValueCreateMutable(kABPersonPhoneProperty);

CFTypeRef phone= CFSTR("123000222111");

ABMultiValueAddValueAndLabel(copyOfPhones, phone,kABPersonPhoneMobileLabel,NULL);

isSuccess = ABRecordSetValue(record, kABPersonPhoneProperty, copyOfPhones, &error);

isSuccess = ABAddressBookAddRecord(ab, record, &error);
isSuccess = ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);

ABGroupAddMember(group, record, &error);

NSLog(@"is success %d", isSuccess);

ABAddressBookSave(ab, &error);
CFRelease(group);
```

Comment: Unfortunately this adds it to the default group...I want it to be a separate group just like "Facebook" is

Comment: First 6 lines of code are creating a new group in your AddressBook. I use the same code in my project and it works fine :-)